# Tango with Django tutorial: "table rango_category has no column named views"

Tags: python, django, sqlite

I've been stuck on this for a while and have gone through all of the suggestions already posted on here and it still won't recognize the column.

So I'm getting this:

```
DatabaseError at /admin/rango/category/add/
table rango_category has no column named views
Request Method: POST
Request URL:    http://127.0.0.1:8000/admin/rango/category/add/
Django Version: 1.5.4
Exception Type: DatabaseError
Exception Value:    
table rango_category has no column named views
```

Here is my models.py for rango

```
from django.db import models

class Category(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=128, unique=True)
    views = models.IntegerField(default=0)
    likes = models.IntegerField(default=0)

    class Meta:
        verbose_name_plural = "Categories"  # otherwise writes "Categorys"

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.name

class Page(models.Model):
    category = models.ForeignKey(Category)
    title = models.CharField(max_length=128)
    url = models.URLField()  # can include max_length if desired
    views = models.IntegerField(default=0)

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.title
```

I've already tried deleting the DB using `python manage.py flush` then doing `python manage.py syncdb` and it gives the same error.  When I do `python manage.py sql rango`, I get:

```
BEGIN;
CREATE TABLE "rango_category" (
    "id" integer NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
    "name" varchar(128) NOT NULL UNIQUE,
    "views" integer NOT NULL,
    "likes" integer NOT NULL
)
;
CREATE TABLE "rango_page" (
    "id" integer NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
    "category_id" integer NOT NULL REFERENCES "rango_category" ("id"),
    "title" varchar(128) NOT NULL,
    "url" varchar(200) NOT NULL,
    "views" integer NOT NULL
)
;
```

... so I'm pretty sure the column named "views" is there.  Any help would be much appreciated!

Comment: Restart the website and try again. Post the code you update the database.

Answer (score 1):

Are you using SQLite? Look at the warning in this section of your tutorial:
http://www.tangowithdjango.com/book/chapters/models.html#creating-and-synchronising-the-database

> Whenever you add to existing database models, you will have to delete the database file and then re-sync the database by running python manage.py syncb again. This is a drawback of Django 1.5.4, and can be quite frustrating. If you however add a new model, you can syncdb your database without having to delete and recreate it. You must therefore bear this in mind when tweaking your database: new models will be synchronised with syncdb - but changes to existing models will not be.

So, I'd delete the sqlite file, then run `manage.py syncdb` again.

Note: Django 1.7 is so much better, and there is a [beta tutorial](http://www.tangowithdjango.com/book17/) for it online.

Comment: Like I said, I tried `flush` and then did `syncdb` again, is there something else I have to do after that?

And thanks for the heads-up with the 1.7 tutorial!  This problem wouldn't even exist in it, so that's really helpful.

Comment: Django `flush` only deletes the database data--not the database design. Therefore, you literally have to delete the sqlite file. Flush: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.5/ref/django-admin/#flush

Comment: Also worth mentioning, Django 1.5 is no longer supported by the Django Project, so don't do any production coding with it.